# How to remove shortcut from start screen?

Tags: powershell, windows-8, windows-server-2012, wsh, startmenu

Basically in an effort to configure and customise the start screen for our Windows 8/2012 users I have resorted to creating shortcuts and copying the layout to each user. With powershell I am able to create my links and shortcuts by running the following:

```
$ws = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
$Dt = $ws.SpecialFolders.item("StartMenu\Wes")
$URL = $ws.CreateShortcut($Dt + "\MYWEBSITE.url")
$URL.TargetPath = "http://MYWEB.MYDOMAIN.com"
$URL.Save()
```

This runs, and if I was to update a url it will also update it in the start screen.

My question is, does anyone know how i can change it so that it removes a shortcut?

Answer (score 2):

A shortcut is just a file. Just call a command to delete it.
BTW, if you're targeting W8/2012 or newer, I would recommend you to move away fro vbscript and onto PowerShell for stuff like this. What you're doing in the above example can easily be done with the
"New-Shortcut" cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

There is no New-Shortcut cmdlet in Server 2012. There are scripts called that, including the one in TechNet Gallery (http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/New-Shortcut-4d6fb3d8), but no native cmdlet.